# Array value store in session as a string.

Tags: php, session

I have an array and it looks like this.

```
[cuisine] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 41
            [5] => 22
        )
```

So now I need to store these values in `SESSION`. Something like this

`$_SESSION['cuisine'] = 36, 12, 2, 4, 41, 22`

This is how I tried it, But it doesn't work for me.

```
if (isset($_POST['cuisine'])) { 
    $cuisine = $_POST['cuisine']; 
    $noCuisine = count($cuisine);

    if($noCuisine >= 1) {

        $cuisines = '';
        for($i=0; $i < $noCuisine; $i++) {
            $cuisines .= $noCuisine[$i] . ", ";

        }
        echo $cuisines;

        $_SESSION['cuisines'] = $cuisines;
    } else {
        $error_alert[] = "Please select at least one Cuisine.";
    }
} else {
    $error_alert[] = "Cuisine field can NOT be empty";
}
```

Can anybody tell me whats the wrong with this? 
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just store the array in the session variable, instead of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$noCuisines[$i]` is wrong. `$noCuisines` is a number, not an array. It should be `$_POST['cuisine'][$i]`.

But that whole loop is unnecessary, since PHP provides a built-in function [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for doing this.

```
$cuisines = implode(', ', $_POST['cuisine']);
```

You could also just store the array in the session variable, rather than converting it to a string:

```
$_SESSION['cuisines'] = $_POST['cuisine'];
```

Comment: If I use second method, Can I check value is an integer, before store in session?

Comment: You can use `array_filter($_POST['cuisine'], 'is_int')` to get all the integer values in the array.

Comment: Barmar, I check it somethig like this, but it seems not working - `if (array_filter($cuisine, 'is_int')) {
   $_SESSION['cuisines'] = $cuisine;
  }`

Comment: `array_filter` doesn't return true or false, it returns an array of all the elements that match the test

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call `session_start()`

Use `$_SESSION['cuisine'] = implode(',', $cuisine)` instead of these statements:

```
$cuisines = '';
for($i=0; $i < $noCuisine; $i++) {
      $cuisines .= $noCuisine[$i] . ", ";

}
echo $cuisines;
$_SESSION['cuisines'] = $cuisines;
```